# Rename the file with current system time

Tags: c#, .net

I'm getting the error "The given path's format is not supported" with this code:

```
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

    string oldname = (Server.MapPath(string.Format("/Projects/" +              
    ddlProjectapplication.SelectedItem.ToString() + "/temp/" + filename)));

   System.IO.File.Move(oldname, oldname+DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

Comment: Look what is done with `DateTime.Now.ToString()` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should at least include exception stack trace but I **guess** it's on `File.Move()` because `DateTime.Now.ToString()` will return something like this (according to current culture):

```
09/04/2014 14:12:00
```

Obvisouly it's not a valid file name (because <kbd>/</kbd> is path separator so you'll have something unexpected and <kbd>:</kbd> is volume separator then it's not valid there and you get *"The given path's format is not supported"*).

What you may do is:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var newName = String.Format("{0}.{1:0000}{2:00}{3:00}-{4:00}{5:00}{6:00}",
    oldName,
    now.Year, now.Month, now.Day,
    now.Hour, now.Minute, now.Second);

System.IO.File.Move(oldname, newName);
```

Also please note that this will add timestamp to filename so `test.txt` will become (with proposed code) something like `test.txt-20140904-141200`. If you want to keep file extension (changing its name) you may do this:

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(oldName);
string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(oldName);
string extension = Path.GetExtensions(oldName);
var now = DateTime.Now;
var newName = String.Format("{0} ({1:0000}{2:00}{3:00}-{4:00}{5:00}{6:00})",
    name,
    now.Year, now.Month, now.Day,
    now.Hour, now.Minute, now.Second);

System.IO.File.Move(oldname,
    System.IO.Path.Combine(path, newName + extension));
```

With this code `test.txt` will become `test (20140904-141200).txt`.

Comment: Thanks Adriano . But iam still getting an error in var newName = String.Format("{0} ({1:0000}{2:00}{3:00}-{4:00}{5:00}{6:00}),
    name ,
    now.Year, now.Month, now.Day,
    now.Hour, now.Minute, now.Second);

Comment: @user3628181 post exact exception strace (better if also dumping oldName and newName variables)

Comment: I don't like `path + newName` wich can be an error. I prefer `Path.Combine(path, newName)`

Comment: @Xaruth if I did remember Path.GetDirectoryName() doesn't include trailing directory separator (adding it by hand) it was not an issue (because GetDirectoryName won't change) but as it was...yes, it was an error!!! Thank you! :)

Comment: Thanks Adriano . Could you check  these code because iam getting an error: "Expected ;" in these line of code " var newName = String.Format("{0} ({1:0000}{2:00}{3:00}-{4:00}{5:00}{6:00}) "

Comment: @user3628181 sorry, typo in my code. there is a missing " character. See updated answer.